# Scio/Apache beam, how to map grouped results

Tags: apache-beam, spotify-scio

I have a simple pipeline that reads from pubsub within a fixed window, parses messages and groups them by a specific property. However if I `map` after the `groupBy` my function doesn't seem to get executed.

Am I missing something?

```
sc.pubsubSubscription[String](s"projects/$project/subscriptions/$subscription")
  .withFixedWindow(Duration.standardSeconds(windowSeconds))
  .map(parseMessage)
  .groupBy(_.ip_address)
  .map(entry => log.info(s"${entry._1} was repeated ${entry._2.size} times"))
```

Comment: Can you speak about how you are testing this? You may be able to test this using Beam's TestStream interface..

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce the issue with the `DirectRunner` and a simple pipeline that reads from Pub/Sub, uses the first word of the message as the key, applies the `GroupByKey` and then logs the entries. Seems like the GBK step waits for all the data to arrive and, as it's an unbounded source, does not emit any result. What worked for me is to define a windowing strategy with triggering such as:

```scala
object PubSubTest {
  private lazy val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)

  def main(cmdlineArgs: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val (sc, args) = ContextAndArgs(cmdlineArgs)

    val defaultInputSub = "test_sub"
    val subscription = args.getOrElse("input", defaultInputSub)
    val project = "PROJECT_ID"

    sc.pubsubSubscription[String](s"projects/$project/subscriptions/$subscription")
      // provide window options including triggering
      .withFixedWindows(duration = Duration.standardSeconds(10), options = WindowOptions(
        trigger = Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
          .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(2))),
        accumulationMode = AccumulationMode.ACCUMULATING_FIRED_PANES,
        closingBehavior = ClosingBehavior.FIRE_IF_NON_EMPTY,
        allowedLateness = Duration.standardSeconds(0))
      )
      // use first word of the Pub/Sub message as the key
      .keyBy(a => a.split(" ")(0))
      .groupByKey
      .map(entry => log.info(s"${entry._1} was repeated ${entry._2.size} times"))

    val result = sc.close().waitUntilFinish()
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! that worked, thanks! I wonder why the behaviour is inconsistent between dataflow and the direct runner